# Regarding the "Find a Stack Exchange Community" search engine, can community members add "Also Known As" terms to help direct people to their site?

Tags: feature-request, search

This question is in reference to this box...

[image]

I found that when I entered terms like "climate change", "clean energy", "renewable", "global warming", etc. that I received no suggestions. (Eventually, with additional research, I discovered that the right to site to join is probably [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).)

Is there a way for community members to define or submit additional terms to Stack Exchange (I'll call them "Also Known As" terms) which the find-a-community search feature will then use to provide better recommendations to someone who is looking for a community to join?

Comment: Another way of finding a site is by browsing through the list and reading the names and descriptions. In that case you can speed the process up a bit by looking a a specific category on the site overview page. For example https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-name lists the 24 sites in the Science category, which is easier to browse than the full list of 182 sites in the dropdown.

Comment: I think you want to search across all sites' _tags_.  Searching for "climate" would find the climate-change tag at Earth Science, but also at Politics and Skeptics, and the climate-science tag at Physics, and perhaps more at other sites.  Would that help you?

Comment: Is searching across all sites' tags something you can do today? If so, how?

Comment: @phil1008 It's probably possible with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), but I don't have a query handy, and SEDE isn't something most users are expected to interact with.

Comment: The list of sites at the link you provided is useful. If an experienced user can use SEDE to help the find-a-site search feature make better suggestions, that would be worth expanding on. If SEDE can only help a new user with "rad skills" do a more advanced search, that's less useful.

Answer (score 6):

This search is using the site names and descriptions, so in order to e.g. have "climate change" trigger the site as result, you can ask in the per-site meta to add it to the site description.

Another option is using a search engine like Google and narrow the results to be only from stackexchange.com e.g. [site:stackexchange.com "global warming"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+%22global+warming%22):

[image: search results for global warming in stack exchange]

Answer (score 4):

I think it doesn't really make sense to add keywords for communities there.

- Firstly, it's a simple tool designed to quickly find a community in a very long list of communities by name—not a search engine.
- Secondly, using that quick menu to find communities using keywords, might give users the idea that a question asking after anything related to the keyword that brought them to a site is on-topic. Which is highly unlikely.